# Beanstalk Log rotation to S3 and lifecycle configuration on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When Elastic Beanstalk creates S3 bucket `"elasticbeanstalk-region-account_id"`? As soon as the environment with enabled S3 log rotation is created or on its first log rotation?

Comment: in general, it's better to ask one question per post

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBT creates S3 bucket when environment is created. This bucket is used not only for logs, that's why. To my experience, logs are saved there on the first occurrence of log rotation. However, I didn't find this in documentation.. But it's only logical to me.